# how to press 'Windows Key' + R pywinauto send_keys function

Tags: python, pywinauto

I've tried to open the "Run" application to execute Windows commands. But I use an ugly function for it. I want to decrease my code size.

I currently use

```
import pywinauto


pywinauto.Application().start("explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}")
```

I want to use

```
import pywinauto


pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('{RWIN} R')
```

but it doesn't work.

[Execution Movie](https://i.imgur.com/KmqByBs.gifv)

I want pywinauto to press the Windows key at the same time as the R key.

Comment: Whats wrong with ur first code, it works and is the same amount of code?

Comment: Alternatively you could use ```pyautogui``` and run ```pyautogui.hotkey("win", "r")```

Comment: I want to fit my code more clean and simple to understand, the first command is long

Answer (score 3):

You are right, in order to make it work you have to keep the `win` key pressed down while pressing `r` key. To achieve this you should use modifiers and actions:

```py
import pywinauto

pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys("{VK_LWIN down}r{VK_LWIN up}")
```

See the related Pywinauto docs: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html?highlight=send_keys#pywinauto-keyboard

Comment: Use  send_keys("{VK_LWIN down}r") is enough to have the expected result